# How is force transmitted through a gravitational well via matter in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, metric-tensor, time-dilation

Lets say we have a hollow spherical shell of mass with a small hole in it. Inside the shell, the gravitation time dilation makes time pass $t_d$ times as fast as time passes infinitely far away. There is a massless taut string which goes from infinity, through the small hole, to the inside of the shell. The part inside the shell is connected to a spring which exerts force F on the string. Thus the tension of the string is F in the shell. At infinity, the other end of the string is attached to another spring. How do I find what the tension is at infinity?

I'm mainly trying to figure out how force is transmitted through matter in curved space. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good question. I'm curious to see the responses. Force has units of mass.length/time^2.  I assume the mass doesn't change. Also, it's difficult to imagine length changing since there's no field gradient inside the shell. However, time dilation will occur due to gravitational potential GM/r.  So I assume the ratio of the forces on the two ends of the massless string is 1-2GM/rc^2, without the usual square-root. But this is pure guesswork. I'm also wondering how tension in the string varies with distance/radius, since gravitational length contraction will also be at play outside the shell.